# Working with reference fields in marshmallow-mongoengine

Tags: mongoengine, marshmallow

How does one dereference ReferenceFields in marshmallow_mongoengine? For example, `dump_data = author_schema.dump(author).data` results in `'5578726b7a58012298a5a7e2'` instead of the more useful response `{title='Fight Club', author=author}`.

```
from marshmallow_mongoengine import ModelSchema

class AuthorSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author

class BookSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

author_schema = AuthorSchema()

author = Author(name='Chuck Paluhniuk').save()
book = Book(title='Fight Club', author=author).save()

dump_data = author_schema.dump(author).data
# {'id': 1, 'name': 'Chuck Paluhniuk', 'books': ['5578726b7a58012298a5a7e2']}

author_schema.load(dump_data).data
# <Author(name='Chuck Paluhniuk')>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nesting schemas](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nesting.html)

```
from marshmallow.fields import Nested

class AuthorSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author        
    books = Nested("BookSchema",many=True)
```